# Python script getting killed in middle while launching threads

Tags: python, multithreading, unit-testing, subprocess, python-multithreading

I have a dictionary with 2000 key value pair key as URL of application and value as command to execute test case of application.

I need to execute those in parallel by using threads and launching test cases command by using sub-process module

After running some of threads and getting output in std out, the subsequent threads are getting stuck and are failing.

I tried by checking with slicing out 500 queue items in my code. It's not get struck and also got mail with report of test cases output.

Please advice me how to avoid strucking of threads in middle.

My code is

```
import Queue
import subprocess
from threading import Thread
SERVER_COMMANDS = {}
TOTAL_OUTPUT  = []
def run_function(server_commands, receivers, url, test_case_name, mail_send=True):
    threads = []
    q_items = []
    counter = 0
    for server, command in server_commands.iteritems():
        q_items.append(dict(counter=counter,server=server, command=command, server_commands=server_commands))
        counter += 1

    Q = Queue.Queue()
    for item in q_items:
        Q.put(item)

    for i in xrange(90):
      th = Thread(target=_run_function, args=(Q,))
      th.start()
      threads.append(th)
    for th in threads:
      th.join()

    total_output = ''.join(TOTAL_OUTPUT)

def _run_function(q):
    while not q.empty():
        args = q.get()
        server = args.get('server')
        command = args.get('command')
        process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
        process.wait()
        output, error = process.communicate()
        print "The thread number is %s" % args.get('counter')
        SERVER_COMMANDS[server] = output
        TOTAL_OUTPUT.append(output)
        for line in output:
            sys.stdout.write(line)
```

To get a better view Please check the [Result Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUcWJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you have a race condition between `q.empty()` and `q.get()`. If another thread gets the last item between those two calls, the thread will block. You should get rid of the call to `q.empty()` and call [`q.get_nowait()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.get_nowait) instead. Then when it raises an `Empty` exception, exit the function.

However, I suspect that your real problem is that you're calling `process.wait()` before `process.communicate()`. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait):

> **Warning** This will deadlock when using `stdout=PIPE` and/or `stderr=PIPE` and the child process generates enough output to a pipe such that it blocks waiting for the OS pipe buffer to accept more data. Use `communicate()` to avoid that.

Just stop calling `process.wait()`.

You might also find the [process pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) easier than launching your own.

Comment: thank you. By specifying the  timeout parameter to q.get(timeout=10) I  overcome the hanging issue in threads